# Problem with using Govuk-Frontend npm package in Oracle JET Application

Tags: javascript, requirejs, node-modules, npm-package, oracle-jet

Problem with 'Get started' (https://frontend.design-system.service.gov.uk/get-started/)

I am trying to use Govuk-Frontend npm package in Oracle JET Application. I have included the package in path_mapping.json and main.js.
When I try to use them in js file I am getting an error saying "**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initAll')**".

js file to be called from the package in node modules  is all.js ..Directory structure in node modules for the package  is Govuk-Frontend/govuk/all.js
I have renamed all.js inside the package to govuk.js.

Error=>
[image]

path_mapping.json =>
[image]

main.js in requirejs.config=>

[image]

dashboard.js =>
[image]

How can I call initAll() function from Govuk-Frontend npm package?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path_mapping.json to:

```
"govuk": {
  "cdn": "3rdparty",
  "cwd": "node_modules/govuk-frontend/govuk",
  "debug": {
    "src": ["**"],
    "path": "libs/govuk",
    "cdnPath": "govuk"
  },
  "release": {
    "src": ["**"],
    "path": "libs/govuk",
    "cdnPath": "govuk"
  }
}
```

add in your index.html

```
<script src="js/libs/govuk/all.js"></script>
<script>
    window.GOVUKFrontend.initAll()
</script>
```